# You've reached the document limit for comments

Tags: google-docs, comments

We are writing a scientific article with the current character count of 135,332 and no active comments or suggestions. Since yesterday, any attempt to make a comment or suggestion leads to this popup:

[image]

> You've reached the document limit for comments. Please make a copy of the document without resolved comments to continue commenting on the new copy.

Since there are no active comments, I understand that this is caused by the history. [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%22You%27ve+reached+the+document+limit+for+comments.%22) shows that this is a very rare problem. Is there any information on the limit of the total number of comments and suggestions? The suggested solution is to follow the advice and make a copy of the document. In our case this is highly undesirable: we have ~10 active editors, the paper is about to be submitted and we really need the history, at least the named versions.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already found your own solution to this (which you can share here) but this

> The suggested solution is to follow the advice and make a copy of the document. In our case this is highly undesirable: we have ~10 active editors, the paper is about to be submitted and we really need the history, at least the named versions.

doesn't make much sense. Whatever journal you're submitting the paper to doesn't really care that much about its history, does it?

We ran into the same error in the case of a 2-year-old file keeping track of various marketing documents. The only workable solutions were using Google's message to copy the information over (nixing the comment history) or copying the sheet into a new file with the same effect.

Whether you need your document's history for your journal or for internal purposes, just keep both the old and new documents bookmarked. Basically, you have your edit history up to date X in one file and your edit history afterwards on the other one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - what you mean is that there is no solution. I also created a new copy w/o history. I didn't write that we needed history for the journal BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a direct solution, I have run into similar problems needing to maintain review history and used some scripts to export all of the comments data to a spreadsheet, then maintained the review conversations in that format. My suggestion would be to maintain that super valuable comment history in a dedicated space (so that it can be searched, filtered and importantly, preserved more intentionally than hidden away in a document's comment history).

This is what my comments Sheets look like. At first, I'll keep a link to the comment for retrieval, the author, status and group comment/reply threads so they can be collapsed for easier reading. After a while, I try to transition the conversation away from comments in the doc and more into the spreadsheet.

[image]

Copying comments data manually is not fun or practical, but you can  automatically export all of your comment data from that document using Apps Script. Other S.O. questions have examples of scripts, but there are now also comments exporter Add-Ons that can do this out-of-the-box.